# Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmardown::pandoc_available)

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, ifconfig

I am working in RStudio **Cloud** and am unable to knit markdowns, with this resulting message:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
Execution halted
```

To fix this, I installed "installr" and attempted to install the pandoc software through this package, but received the following error:

```
Error in system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE) : error in running command
```

The pandoc_available command resulted in this error:

```
pandoc_available(version = NULL, error = FALSE)
Error in pandoc_available(version = NULL, error = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "pandoc_available"

pandoc_available()
Error in pandoc_available() : could not find function "pandoc_available"
```

Is there a way to get RStudio to successfully recognize and install pandoc version 1.12.3? For context, I was able to knit markdowns until just recently. Was there an update to pandoc?

Thanks!